# How to simulate the python operator "in" in Java?

Tags: java

That's a very beautiful operator and it's really frustrating to don't have it in Java.

```
if ("Nova Categoria" in textField1.getText()) {
        textField1.setText("");
        textField1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
```

The bloody "==" does not give me what I want, and my *Pythonic Mind* can't give me the solution to this right now, because I want an "in".

How would you simulate an "in" operator in Java?

Comment: `if (textField1.getText().contains("Nova Categoria"))`.

Comment: Why do you use Java in the first place if you don't like it.
Can't you use a JVM compatible language that you like?

Comment: `textField1.getText().contains("Nova Categoria")`?

Comment: @lc2817 Unfortunately, there are a great many reasons to be tied to tools you don't like. Most Python programmers I know don't *hate* Java, it's just it's insanely verbose compared to Python, which is grating.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/ is a good place to go if you want to check if there exists a method you'd like to use in Java

Comment: @Lattyware yes but in that case, why complaining, you just have to play by the rules of the language

Comment: Also, never use `==` to check for String equality in Java. Use `.equals` instead.

Comment: @lc2817 Complaining is good, it means that in the future (be it with updates, or new languages) the poor design is more likely to be fixed. (I'm not saying that anything more verbose than Python is poor design, but I think even the most hardcore Java idealist has to admit the language has some issues).

Comment: Thank you very much you all, the method works perfectly! Sorry to disturb you all, but this silly question might be useful to someone too. And thanks for tip, CoderTian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (textField1.getText().contains("Nova Categoria"))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `contains` method of `String` instead as follows:

```
if (textField1.getText().contains("Nova Categoria")) {
        textField1.setText("");
        textField1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
```

Look here [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to know more about this method.